# Using IFERROR with complex COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that is dividing 2 COUNTIFS, in some of the results I am getting #DIV/0!. I know there is a way to use IFERROR I just can't seem to find the correct placement for it. Where in the below code to I enter in the IFERROR pieces?

```
=COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">0")/COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">=0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">0")/COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">=0"),"Error Message Here")
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrap everything in the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">0")/COUNTIF(M2:M1500,">=0"),"")
```

The first arguments is your expression. The second argument is what to do in case your expression fails.